# Asking for user input in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need batch code that if a user types yes goto :yes
if type anything else goto :no

this is my code

```
@echo off
title CMD

:main
CLS
set /p input= 
if %input%==yes goto yes
else goto no
goto main

:yes
cls
echo you typed yes
pause>nul
exit

:no
cls
echo you typed something other then yes
pause>nul
exit
```

But it doesn't work, how can i get this to work?
So far if you type yes it goes to :yes
But if you type something else it just goes to a blank screen.

Comment: Duplicate --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247390/how-to-get-user-input-batch

Answer (score 1):

You need some `()` in your `IF/ELSE`.

Try this:

```
@echo off
title CMD

:main
CLS
set /p input= 
if %input%==yes (
    goto yes
) else (
    goto no
)
goto main

:yes
cls
echo you typed yes
pause>nul
exit

:no
cls
echo you typed something other then yes
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: you should wriet `if /i "%input%"=="yes"`. `/i` ignores capitalization, the `"`s prevent from syntax error when user just hits return (blank entry(

Comment: Yes, those are good ideas. I just used the original code and added the parentheses to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
@echo off
title CMD

:main
CLS
set /p input= 
if %input%==yes goto yes
else(if(%input%==no)):goto no
goto main

:yes
cls
echo you typed yes
pause>nul
exit

:no
cls
echo you typed no
pause>nul
exit
```