# How to make a batch file read and respond to text input using set/p

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file that asks 3 questions. There is one correct answer to the questions, and if you get it right, it goes to the next question. If you get all of them right, it says something and closes itself. If you get any one of them wrong, it opens another batch file. All the other answers to similar questions had multiple choice questions, whereas I need one with a single answer. One post on this website answered the question, but I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get user input - batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247390/how-to-get-user-input-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
:firstquestion
cls
set /p question1="Type your question here. For fanciness, add this character.> "
if "%question1%"=="answer" (
goto secondquestion
) else (
echo WRONG!
pause
exit
)
:secondquestion
cls
set /p question2="Type your question here. For fanciness, add this character.> "
if "%question2%"=="answer" (
goto thirdquestion
) else (
echo WRONG!
pause
exit
)
:thirdquestion
cls
set /p question3="Type your question here. For fanciness, add this character.> "
if "%question3%"=="answer" (
goto win
) else (
echo WRONG!
pause
exit
)
:win
cls
echo Victory Message.
pause
```

Below is a comprehensive list of all the commands I used in the above example. This is your basic setup for this kind of quiz.

`@echo off` - This is removes unnecessary echoes.

`:` - Use this as a group of sorts. Use the `goto` command to jump to this group.

`cls` - Clears the command prompt.

`set /p variable="message"` - Creates a variable that is set to whatever the user responds with.

`if/else` - Use this to detect whether the variable matches what you want the correct answer to be.

`echo Message` - Use this to tell the user something. Use `echo.` to add a text break.

`pause` - This stops all code until a user presses any key.

`exit` - Exits the command prompt.

Comment: Are the quotes neccesary? do they show up?

Comment: @Zopolis4 The quotes for the `set /p` command are, but for the `if` command, they are only necessary if the answer is multiple words. They don't show up, so don't worry.

Comment: The quotes in the `if` statement are also necessary to prevent the script from breaking if the user enters nothing. The quotes in the `set` statement show up, but won't if you move the first quote to the left side of the variable name, like this: `set "question1=Type your question here. For fanciness, add this character.> "`

Comment: @SomethingDark I do agree with using quotes for the `if`, but I only use them if I specifically want to prevent the user from typing nothing, or if the statement has multiple words. I have also found that using the `set /p` command has never shown up the quotes that I've used. That is my personal experience, however some people may do whatever suits them best. Lots of times you'll find that one solution works more than others, but a majority of times it really does depend on the circumstances. Thanks for pointing that out!