# Batch script to delete a file when unlocked

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a script that can delete a file when the file is unlocked.

After some modifications I have a simple script that seems to work as long as I can type in the correct filename+location.

```
@echo off
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%

:loop
2>nul (
  (call ) >>"%input%"
) || (
  echo Trying to access file
  timeout /nobreak 5 >nul
  goto loop
)

copy "%input%" d:\tmp\
del "%input%"
```

Comment: The `SET /P` command is used to accept user input.  This topic has been covered several times on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get user input - batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247390/how-to-get-user-input-batch)

Comment: It is not quite what I am trying to accomplish. First i want to specify which subdirectory to look in, then a specific filname. Would like to allow use of *. Someting like: script.bat d:\tmp\test te*.pdf.